# Separate certain columns for two different dataframes?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have to separate rows from two dataframes based on a similar column from df1

df1

```
            A      B
        0  john   id1
        1  parker id2
        2  david  id3
        3  will   id4
```

df2

```
            C          B
        0  letterj    id1
        1  letterp    id2
        2  letterd    id3
        3  letterw    id4
        4  lettert    id5
        5  lettero    id7
```

final_df

```
            A           B 
        4  lettert    id5
        5  lettero    id7
```

Comment: `df2[~df2['B'].isin(df1['B'])]` ?

Answer (score 0):

Just use `isin()`:

```
final_df = df2[~df2['B'].isin(df1['B'].values.tolist())]
```